# How my jQuery function work on whole table?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem in my code. My jQuery code is only implement of the first row of table not on others. Here is my code:

```
   <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['serial no.'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pname'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="prate"  name = "uprice" value="<?php echo $prate = $row['uprice'];?>"></td>
                <td> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pqty" name = "quantity" value ="<?php $quant = ""; echo $quant; ?>"></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pTotal" name = "price" value = "<?php $tprice = ""; echo $tprice; ?>" ></td>
    </tr>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<script>
              $("#prate").keyup(function(){
                // console.log('presssed');

          var prate = document.getElementById('prate').value;
          var pqty = document.getElementById('pqty').value;
          var ptotal = parseInt(prate) * parseInt(pqty);

          document.getElementById('pTotal').value = ptotal;
        });

        $("#pqty").keyup(function(){
          // console.log('presssed');
          var prate = document.getElementById('prate').value;
          var pqty = document.getElementById('pqty').value;
          var ptotal = parseInt(prate) * parseInt(pqty);

          document.getElementById('pTotal').value = ptotal;
        });
        </script>
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Id must be unique. Edit your question to include the rendered HTML (whole table not only tr) rather than the PHP code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Its not clear from your post if rows are added to the table at some point. If they are, the `keyup` event will only be binded to the static items. New dynamic items will not be effected by the events. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is (1) Gather all those classes in a Variable. (2) Run Foreach loop on each element. (3) While looping each element, you must sum all of these elements' values.

```
// Step 1: Fetch Classes
var FetchedClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass"); 
var Sum = 0;
// Step 2: Iterate them
Array.prototype.forEach.call(FetchedClasses, function(element) {
  // Step 3: Sum up their values
  Sum = Sum + element.value; //
});
// Now Show it anywhere you like.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector (not id selector) and `each` method to emplement your desired commands on all rows.

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique, instead put a class as a reference for each table data and try each method:

```
 $('.pqty').each(function(i, element){
    $(element).keyup(function(evt) { 
        /* anything */
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, id must be unique on whole page. So on each row and items, either you have make unique id (Which will be complicated to bind event), so you can go with class or as below script for binding the events.

```
<script>
        $('input[name="uprice"]').keyup(function(){
        
          var prate = $(this).val();
          var pqty = $(this).parent().next().find('input[name="quantity"]').val();
          var ptotal = parseInt(prate) * parseInt(pqty);

         $(this).parent().next().next().find('input[name="price"]').val(ptotal);
        });

        $('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function(){
          var prate = $(this).parent().prev().find('input[name="uprice"]').val();;
          var pqty = $(this).val();
          var ptotal = parseInt(prate) * parseInt(pqty);

          $(this).parent().next().find('input[name="price"]').val(ptotal);
        });
</script>
```

Not have tested but should help you.